# Load groovy files into jenkins and invoke the files just like invoking shared library files

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have multiple groovy files which are wrote as a library files and one file is invoked in another file using file name.
To avoid git dependency we are trying to load pipeline shared library from local repository.
I want to load all groovy files into jenkins runtime and invoke it using file name.
Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'load' from pipeline functions

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/

```
pipeline = load 'pipeline.groovy'
pipeline.functionA()
```

where pipeline.groovy

```
def functionA() {
  println("hi")
}
return this;
```

how to do it dynamically?i dont think its possible to do without rewriting huge code of CpsGroovyShellFactory